# How to get large size images from gallery instead of thumbnail size, using Facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get bigger size images from FB gallery using the Facebook graph 2.9.
I have tried with type=large, but id doesn't seem to work.

Any solutions?

Here's my code:

```
// Get album id from url
$album_id = isset($_GET['album_id'])?$_GET['album_id']:header("Location: index_photos.php");
$album_name = isset($_GET['album_name'])?$_GET['album_name']:header("Location: index_photos.php");

// Get access token from session
$access_token = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];

// Get photos of Facebook page album using Facebook Graph API
$graphPhoLink = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{$album_id}/photos?fields=source,images,name&access_token={$access_token}";
$jsonData = file_get_contents($graphPhoLink);
$fbPhotoObj = json_decode($jsonData, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

// Facebook photos content
$fbPhotoData = $fbPhotoObj['data'];
?>

<?php
// Render all photos
foreach($fbPhotoData as $data){
    $imageData = end($data['images']);
    $imgSource = isset($imageData['source'])?$imageData['source']:'';
    $name = isset($data['name'])?$data['name']:'';

    echo "<div class='fb-album-preview'>";
    echo "<img src='{$imgSource}' alt=''>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking ... `source` is the largest available version already, so what more do you want?

Comment: Well this is the size that i get, instead of the original size like on FB gallery:

http://www.mostarrockschool.org/photos.php?album_id=1689022814465445&album_name=50

Comment: No clue what that URL is supposed to prove (that doesn’t seem to show any image from Facebook, just a static map image?)  ... please be specific.

Comment: Ok, this is the page that I'm working on.  The url is a listing of a certain Facebook gallery album photos, that I got through Facebook API.
The size of these listed photos is very small comparing to the size of these photos on the Facebook. 
For example:
https://www.facebook.com/MostarRockSchool/photos/a.1689022814465445.1073741862.457725324261873/1689026887798371/?type=3&theater

That image on FB is much bigger then on my page (first image):

http://www.mostarrockschool.org/photos.php?album_id=1689022814465445&album_name=50

Comment: Sorry URL was broken, but now should be ok

Comment: `images` contains all available sizes, so pick one from those.

Comment: @redsky try like this picture.type(large){url}